# Save the name of a selected option from a List Box to winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

I am making a program with the Win32 API, where I must register products and shipments. In one of the windows, the names of the products must appear in a ListBox.

What I want to do is that, when the user selects an option from the ListBox, the name of this option is saved in a variable of type `wchar_t[]` to use it later. For example, if the user selects the `"Orange Juice"` option, I want the name `"Orange Juice"` to be saved in the variable.

Is there a way to do this? I've already tried different ways, but they don't work.

```
struct Product {
    wchar_t name[50]{};
    wchar_t price[10]{};
    wchar_t descrpt[80]{};
    Product* antE{};
    Product* sigU{};
};

Product* start = NULL;

BOOL CALLBACK my_product(HWND window_PROduct, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            long opc = LOWORD(wParam);
            MENU(window_PROduct, opc);

            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_LIST1: {
                    if (HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_SELCHANGE) {
                        int select = SendDlgItemMessage(window_PROduct, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETCURSEL, NULL, NULL);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            SendDlgItemMessage(window_PROduct, IDC_LIST1, LB_RESETCONTENT, NULL, NULL);

            if (start == NULL) {
                break;
            }

            Product* aux = start;
            while (aux != NULL) {
                SendDlgItemMessage(window_PROduct, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)aux->name);
                aux = aux->sigU;
            }
            break;
        }

        default: {
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use `LB_GETTEXT` to get the text from a listbox item.

Comment: ... and [`LB_GETTEXTLEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-gettextlen) to find out how long it is first, so that you can allocate a buffer to stuff it into.